# Statistics: Adding up averages

Tags: statistics

Let's assume we the average income for a journalist is $10000$ (in the whole country).

In a certain state X the average income for this profession is $10700$, therefore 7% higher. Also, the average income (in the whole country) is $11500$ (15% higher), when working for a big company.

Can I say something about the average income for a journalist in state X, when working for a big company? Is this as simple as multiplying both values like $10000*1.07*1.15$? This would mean the income would be ~23% higher?

(This is not homework.)

Comment: I wouldn't want to suppose these two events were independent.  Maybe a disproportionate number of journalists in state $X$ work for big companies, in which case the $7\%$ already reflects the "big company" bonus.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes" if you make some assumptions: that all the jobs in big companies pay the same extra 15%, and that this state is typical of the whole country.

Congratulations for using "multiply by 1.15" to compute a 15% increase.